Ошибка в употреблении деепричастного оборота
Почему в этих предложениях употребление деепричастных оборотов ошибочно?

В центре было расположено здание, сияя белыми стенами.

Пользователи не готовы к встрече с мошенниками, рискуя потерять средства.


В обоих случаях субъект совпадает, предложение не безличное, однако что-то не так. Суть в отсутствии глагольного сказуемого? Если так, то где об этом почитать?


Действительно, предложения выглядят некорректно, а почему?

Вот правило Розенталя: §212. Деепричастные обороты
Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают, например: «Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана».
Страдательной конструкцией здесь является сказуемое в форме краткого причастия прошедшего времени: книга была издана.

Рассмотрим предложение: В центре было расположено здание, сияя белыми стенами.

Вариант правильной записи: В центре было расположено здание, сияющее белыми стенами (которое сияло белыми стенами).
В исходном варианте очевидная страдательная конструкция: было расположено здание.

Рассмотрим предложение: Пользователи не готовы к встрече с мошенниками, рискуя потерять средства.

Здесь некорректны смысловые отношения между сказуемым и деепричастием, в действительности там причинно-следственная связь между предиктивными формами.
Возможная запись сообщения: Пользователи не готовы к встрече с мошенниками и поэтому рискуют потерять средства.
Неподготовленные к встрече  с мошенниками,  пользователи рискуют потерять средства.
Вариант с деепричастием:  Не будучи подготовленными к встрече с мошенниками, пользователи рискуют потерять средства.

Ошибка в предложении связана с неправильно построенной конструкцией деепричастного оборота.В данном случае деепричастие "сияя" должно описывать действие, которое совершает подлежащее. Однако подлежащее в предложении — не "здание".
Правильный вариант может быть таким:
"В центре было расположено здание с сияющими белыми стенами" или "В центре было расположено здание, которое сияло белыми стенами".
Во втором предложении связана с деепричастным оборотом "рискуя потерять средства". Деепричастие должно указывать на действие, которое совершает подлежащее, но здесь оно описывает потенциальное действие пользователей, а не их готовность.
Правильный вариант: "Пользователи, рискуя потерять средства, не готовы к встрече с мошенниками." Или: "Пользователи не готовы к встрече с мошенниками, так как рискуют потерять средства."
